# Django template OBJECT from FOR loop into Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, django

Its a Django template which have FOR LOOP and contain 1 DIV in it.

```
{% for player in players_details %}
    <div data-playerId="{{ player }}" class=" my_player_id >
    .... some functionality .....
    </div> 
{% endfor %}
```

1. Multiple div will be generated wrt Objects in for loop

2. Now Model will open on above div click

```
//THIS IS JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION
$(".my_player_id").click(function(){
    var myPlayer = $(this).data('playerId');
    console.log(myPlayer);
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

3. Now Problem is i am not getting objects in javascript

```
Inside DIV
    <div data-playerId="{{ player }}"
Inside JS
    var myPlayer = $(this).data('playerId');
```

4. Note : Its Working fine for 1 Object data(object.data)

```
This is working   
    <div data-playerId="{{ player.name }}"
Inside JS
    var myPlayer = $(this).data('playerId');
```

Comment: If your player object has property of id you can pass it as `data-playerId="{{ player.id }}"`

Comment: I am able to send individual elements of object [ player.id or player.name ] but i want to send whole object [ Player ] , as in Modal i want to show many attributes of player and dont want  to call ajax to get all attributes with player.id (1 attr) if possible

Comment: that is not possible. You can't get django objects in there. consider creating the modals inside the forloop. ie., each modal for each object. You can use forloop counter to uniquely identify the pop up to be shown.